# convert month_year value to month name and year columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I've a sample dataframe

```
year_month
202004
202005
202011
202012
```

How can I append the month_name + year column to the dataframe

```
year_month    month_name
202004        April 2020
202005        May 2020
202011        Nov 2020
202112        Dec 2021
```

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: @CryptoFool Sure would try it out first, if it doesn't work, then I'll ask here.!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.strptime` to convert your string into a `datetime` object, then you can use `datetime.strftime` to convert it back into a string with different format.

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['202004', '202005', '202011', '202012'], columns=['year_month'])
>>> df['month_name'] = df['year_month'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m').strftime('%b %Y'))
>>> df
  year_month month_name
0     202004   Apr 2020
1     202005   May 2020
2     202011   Nov 2020
3     202012   Dec 2020
```

You can see the full list of [format codes here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: Why not use the pandas built-in, `df['month_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'], format='%Y%m').dt.strftime('%b %Y')`? Avoids the iteration by `apply`.